# Where can I find the maximum value of length and width that a PMOS or NMOS supports?

Tags: mosfet, spice, asic

I searched the web but didn't come up with something good. I am using the `0_25umMODEL_TYP.md` module of spice. I was wondering, what is the maximum size transistor the technology supports, so that I can do an accurate simulation?

```
* 0.25um model

.PARAM dxl=0
.PARAM dxw=0
.PARAM TOxN=5nm
.PARAM dVthN=0
.PARAM CjN=1.9E-3
.PARAM CjswN=4.4E-10
.PARAM TOxP=5nm
.PARAM dVthP=0
.PARAM CjP=1.9E-3
.PARAM CjswP=3.8E-10
.PARAM Poly_RSH=150
.PARAM MIM_Carea=2fF

.MODEL NMOS NMOS (                                 LEVEL   = 49
+VERSION = 3.1            TNOM    = 27             TOX     = 5.6E-9
+XJ      = 1E-7           NCH     = 2.3549E17      VTH0    = '0.3703728+dVthN'
+K1      = 0.4681093      K2      = 7.541163E-4    K3      = 1E-3
+K3B     = 1.6723088      W0      = 1E-7           NLX     = 1.586853E-7
+DVT0W   = 0              DVT1W   = 0              DVT2W   = 0
+DVT0    = 0.5681239      DVT1    = 0.6650313      DVT2    = -0.5
+U0      = 284.0529492    UA      = -1.538419E-9   UB      = 2.706778E-18
+UC      = 2.748569E-11   VSAT    = 1.293771E5     A0      = 1.5758996
+AGS     = 0.2933081      B0      = -5.433191E-9   B1      = -1E-7
+KETA    = -4.899001E-3   A1      = 3.196943E-5    A2      = 0.5018403
+RDSW    = 126.2217131    PRWG    = 0.5            PRWB    = -0.2
+WR      = 1              WINT    = 0              LINT    = 1.34656E-9
+XL      = 'dxl'          XW      = '-4E-8+dxw'    DWG     = -1.127362E-8
+DWB     = -3.779056E-9   VOFF    = -0.0891381     NFACTOR = 1.29317
+CIT     = 0              CDSC    = 2.4E-4         CDSCD   = 0
+CDSCB   = 0              ETA0    = 6.291887E-3    ETAB    = 3.385328E-4
+DSUB    = 0.0449797      PCLM    = 1.5905872      PDIBLC1 = 1
+PDIBLC2 = 2.421388E-3    PDIBLCB = -0.0752287     DROUT   = 0.9999731
+PSCBE1  = 7.947415E10    PSCBE2  = 5.8496E-10     PVAG    = 1.01007E-7
+DELTA   = 0.01           RSH     = 3.9            MOBMOD  = 1
+PRT     = 0              UTE     = -1.5           KT1     = -0.11
+KT1L    = 0              KT2     = 0.022          UA1     = 4.31E-9
+UB1     = -7.61E-18      UC1     = -5.6E-11       AT      = 3.3E4
+WL      = 0              WLN     = 1              WW      = 0
+WWN     = 1              WWL     = 0              LL      = 0
+LLN     = 1              LW      = 0              LWN     = 1
+LWL     = 0              CAPMOD  = 2              XPART   = 0.5
+CGDO    = 4.65E-10       CGSO    = 4.65E-10       CGBO    = 5E-10
+CJ      = 1.698946E-3    PB      = 0.99           MJ      = 0.450283
+CJSW    = 3.872151E-10   PBSW    = 0.8211413      MJSW    = 0.2881135
+CJSWG   = 3.29E-10       PBSWG   = 0.8211413      MJSWG   = 0.2881135
+CF      = 0              PVTH0   = -9.283858E-3   PRDSW   = -10
+PK2     = 4.074676E-3    WKETA   = 7.164908E-3    LKETA   = -7.349276E-3    )
*
.MODEL PMOS PMOS (                                 LEVEL   = 49
+VERSION = 3.1            TNOM    = 27             TOX     = 5.6E-9
+XJ      = 1E-7           NCH     = 4.1589E17      VTH0    = '-0.4935548+dVthP'
+K1      = 0.6143278      K2      = 6.804492E-4    K3      = 0
+K3B     = 5.8844074      W0      = 1E-6           NLX     = 6.938169E-9
+DVT0W   = 0              DVT1W   = 0              DVT2W   = 0
+DVT0    = 2.3578746      DVT1    = 0.7014778      DVT2    = -0.1881376
+U0      = 100            UA      = 9.119231E-10   UB      = 1E-21
+UC      = -1E-10         VSAT    = 1.782051E5     A0      = 0.9704347
+AGS     = 0.1073973      B0      = 2.773991E-7    B1      = 8.423987E-7
+KETA    = 0.0104811      A1      = 0.0193128      A2      = 0.3
+RDSW    = 694.5830247    PRWG    = 0.3169639      PRWB    = -0.1958978
+WR      = 1              WINT    = 0              LINT    = 2.971337E-8
+XL      = 'dxl'          XW      = '-4E-8+dxw'    DWG     = -2.967296E-8
+DWB     = -2.31786E-10   VOFF    = -0.1152095     NFACTOR = 1.1064678
+CIT     = 0              CDSC    = 2.4E-4         CDSCD   = 0
+CDSCB   = 0              ETA0    = 0.3676411      ETAB    = -0.0915241
+DSUB    = 1.1089801      PCLM    = 1.3226289      PDIBLC1 = 9.913816E-3
+PDIBLC2 = -1.499968E-6   PDIBLCB = -1E-3          DROUT   = 0.1276027
+PSCBE1  = 8E10           PSCBE2  = 5.772776E-10   PVAG    = 0.0135936
+DELTA   = 0.01           RSH     = 3              MOBMOD  = 1
+PRT     = 0              UTE     = -1.5           KT1     = -0.11
+KT1L    = 0              KT2     = 0.022          UA1     = 4.31E-9
+UB1     = -7.61E-18      UC1     = -5.6E-11       AT      = 3.3E4
+WL      = 0              WLN     = 1              WW      = 0
+WWN     = 1              WWL     = 0              LL      = 0
+LLN     = 1              LW      = 0              LWN     = 1
+LWL     = 0              CAPMOD  = 2              XPART   = 0.5
+CGDO    = 5.59E-10       CGSO    = 5.59E-10       CGBO    = 5E-10
+CJ      = 1.857995E-3    PB      = 0.9771691      MJ      = 0.4686434
+CJSW    = 3.426642E-10   PBSW    = 0.871788       MJSW    = 0.3314778
+CJSWG   = 2.5E-10        PBSWG   = 0.871788       MJSWG   = 0.3314778
+CF      = 0              PVTH0   = 4.137981E-3    PRDSW   = 7.2931065
+PK2     = 2.600307E-3    WKETA   = 0.0192532      LKETA   = -5.972879E-3    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model will probably support whatever you throw at it. After all, a model is only a fancy mathematical equation - there are not usually any constraints. Without any particular context, such as a manufacturing process, there really isn't a good way to figure out an upper limit.

If you got the model from a design kit, then there would be boatloads of documentation on what specific structures the model fit was based on, and the boundaries at which the model no longer accurately portrays the device.

Since you have neither the documentation or the process that goes along with it, I can suggest some boundaries for length and width for reasonable design.

```
Minimum Length:   0.25 um
Maximum Length: 100.00 um
Minimum Width:    0.25 um
Maximum Width:  100.00 um
```

Note that you can create a larger effective width by simply adding more copies of the transistor. You can do this through the model by declaring the number of fingers, or the multiplicity of the device. This lets you get larger transistors without the downfalls of really wide gates. For a longest effective width, I'd probably say the biggest I've seen on an IC is 2,000um to 5,000um for LNA input transistors. I don't think you should need anything so large (unless you're designing an LNA).

Comment: I assume a LNA contain a differentiel AMP so it is reasonable 1000um isn't it? i should use 10 transistor of size 100um or one of 1000um and put it with 10 fingers?

Comment: A Low Noise Amplifier consists of 1-2 transistors operating as a common-source or cascode amplifier. The transistors are so large due to the desire to minimize noise. A normal differential amp would use much smaller transistors. A 100-200um wide transistor is big.

Comment: In a real process, I would try to keep the transistor width less than about 10um, and then use multiplicity or fingering to increase the effective width. You could also probably get away with just using the width you want, since the long poly effects of wide gates doesn't appear to be modeled.